# Javascript: Need help converting from America Central Time (with no DST) to America/New_York with DST

Tags: javascript, date

I get a timestamp from my vendor which is in America Central Time but with no DST.    I need to convert that to America/New_York with DST (when applicable).

I tried using just regular JavaScript then moved over to Moment.   I have tried various approaches but can't get the results I am expecting.  I am open to pretty much any library.  I don't have to use Moment.

Below are three of the many approaches I have tried.

Code Snippet:

```
console.log(sendTimeString);
let d = moment(sendTimeString, "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A"); 
console.log("formatted " + d.clone().tz("America/New_York").format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A'));
```

Produces:

6/12/2019 6:35:36 AM

formatted 06/12/2019 6:35:36 AM

That is the same date and time.  If I do below, I get the correct answer, for now, but it will be off once DST ends.  And even if this worked, it is nothing more than a hack.   I would like to do it correctly.

Code Snippet:

```
console.log(sendTimeString);
let d = moment(sendTimeString, "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A");
console.log("formatted " + d.clone().utcOffset(-2).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A'));
```

Produces:

6/12/2019 6:35:36 AM

formatted 06/12/2019 8:35:36 AM

It seems to me the way to do it is to set the time to UTC with a hardcoded offset, -6.  Then I would pull it up with the America/New_York timezone and everything would be perfect.   But clearly I am not setting this correctly:

Code Snippet:

```
console.log(sendTimeString);
let d = moment(sendTimeString, "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A").utcOffset(-6);
console.log("formatted " + d.clone().tz("America/New_York").format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A'));
```

Produces:

6/12/2019 6:35:36 AM

formatted 06/12/2019 6:35:36 AM

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your first attempt was the closest to what you intended, you just have to specify the input timezone.

```js
// Take the input from the client, specify the format and their timezone
const input = moment.tz('6/12/2019 6:35:36 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A', 'US/Central')

console.log(input.tz())
console.log(input.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A'))

// Convert to your timezone
const output = input.clone().tz('America/New_York')

console.log(output.tz())
console.log(output.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.26/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Moment Timezone's documentation on [parsing ambiguity](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-ambiguous-inputs/) may address your concerns regarding DST.

Comment: Nitpick: Identifiers in the IANA timezone database are *representative locations*, not timezones. A timezone covers a standard offset from UTC for a region. A representative location includes the historic offset and daylight saving rules for a particular administrative area represented by a single location within a timezone. There may be many representative locations in the same timezone with different rules, e.g. Australia/Brisbane, Australia/Sydney and Australia/Melbourne are all in the same timezone but have different historic daylight saving and standard offset rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not exactly what I want.   My vendor gives me date in Central Time Zone but never includes DST.  So right now, there is a 2 hour difference in what I get back to my actual EDST time that I want.   After the time change next month, it will be 1 hour.